# Concurrent Modification of separate sections of my MediaWiki always result in conflicts

Tags: merge, wiki, mediawiki

I have set up a private mediawiki server for the purpose of documentation of a group project, everything is working nicely except for when two users attempt to edit the same article.

When using Wikipedia multiple users are able to edit separate sections of the same article without it causing merge conflicts, but for some reason I am experiencing merge conflicts on my mediawiki server under the same circumstances.

Product and Version:

- MediaWiki - 1.18.1
- PHP - 5.2.17 (apache2handler)
- MySQL - 5.1.57

I have tried the usual search and you will find technique, but unfortunately I have not been able to find any reason for this to be happening. It is very frustrating to not be able to have concurrent modification on our articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic resolution of simultaneous edits is done by shelling out to the GNU diff3 command; if it's not found at installation time (or if it's no longer callable) then all conflicts must be resolved manually, even if they're plainly separate sections.

Check your LocalSettings.php for a bit like this:

# Path to the GNU diff3 utility. Used for conflict resolution.

$wgDiff3 = "/usr/bin/diff3";

and make sure it's correct. If it is correct, check that there's no limitations on PHP shelling out to programs (safe mode etc).